Why my permanent redirection disappear after 1hour (ovh)?
I'm trying to transfer my OVH domain name to Odoo. I followed their procedure, which involves creating a CNAME record from www.domain.eu to domain.odoo.com, and then creating a 301 redirect from domain.eu to https://www.domain.eu.
I can access the site via www.domain.eu but not via domain.eu. I notice that on OVH, the 301 redirect disappears from the list after a while...
I tried to remove some DNS zones.
